# When trying to print a linked list nodes the program is turning off

Tags: c

I am writing a phonebook code using singly linked list. When I try to print the contacts they are printed but then the program turns off.

This is the node struct:

```
struct contact{
  char *number;
  char *name;
  struct contact* next;
};
typedef struct contact contact;
```

and this is the printing contacts function:

```
void list(){
    contact *temp = first;
    if(first==NULL){
      printf("list is empty\n");
    }
    while(temp!=NULL){
      printf("name: %s  number: %s\n", temp->name, temp->number);
      temp = temp->next;
      
    }
    getch();
    system("cls");
  menu();
}
```

menu() function:

```
void menu(){
       system("cls");
  printf("+++++++++++++++++++Phone book+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n     1.add.\n     2.delete.\n     3.search.\n     4.modify.\n     5.list contacts.\n     6.recent\n     7.exit\n ");
  switch(getch())
  {
    case '1':
        add();
        break;
    case '2':
        delete();
        break;
    case '3':
        search();
        break;
    case '4':
        modify();
        break;
    case '5':
        list();
        break;
    case '6':
        recent();
        break;
    case '7':
        exit(0);
        break;
    default: system("cls");
                printf("\nPress any key");
                getch();
menu();
}
}
```

edit:
the add function:

```
void add(){
  system("cls");
  contact* new = (contact*)malloc(sizeof(contact));
  char newname[MAX];
  char newnumber[MAX];
  printf("enter a name \n");
  gets(newname);
  printf("enter a number \n");
  gets(newnumber);
  new-> number = newnumber;
  new->name = newname;
  if(first== NULL){
    first= new;
  }
    else{
    if(first->name[0]>newname[0]){
      new->next = first;
      first = new;
    }
    else{
    contact* temp = first;
    while(temp->next!= NULL && temp->next->name[0]<newname[0]){  
      temp = temp-> next;
    }
    new->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = new;
    getch();

  }


}
file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fprintf(file, "%s %s", newname, newnumber);
fclose(file);

system("cls");
menu();
}
```

Comment: This is not a [mre]. At least we need the `add` function to see how you create your nodes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add` function invokes Undefined Behaviour (the hell of C programmers) because you use local arrays after the functions where they are declared returns, and get only *dangling* pointers:

```
void add(){
  system("cls");
  contact* new = (contact*)malloc(sizeof(contact)); // ok you allocated a contact
  char newname[MAX];            // Oops a local array...
  char newnumber[MAX];          // and another one
  ...
  new-> number = newnumber;     // new->number points to the local array
  new->name = newname;          // id. for new->name
  ...
}                               // newname and newnumber both reach end of life...
```

When the add function returns, `new->name` and `new->number` point to object that have reached their end of life and are *dangling* pointers. Dereferencing them is explicitely Undefined Behaviour.

You should either use `strdup` to copy the content of `newname` and `newnumber` in dynamic memory:

```
  ...
  new-> number = strdup(newnumber);   // new->number points to allocated memory: fine
  new->name = strdup(newname);        // id. for new->name
  ...
```

, or directly use plain arrays in the `contact` struct:

```
struct contact{
  char number[MAX];
  char name[MAX];
  struct contact* next;
};
...
void add(){
  system("cls");
  contact* new = (contact*)malloc(sizeof(contact));
  printf("enter a name \n");
  gets(new->name);
  printf("enter a number \n");
  gets(new->number);
  ...
```

Unrelated, but you should stop using the deprecated `gets` and only use `fgets`. `gets` was deprecated because it was known for decades as the cause of numerous (and impossible to prevent) buffer overflows.